# Call a parent component function from a child component in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to call my `close()` function which is in the parent component from the child component in Angular.

Here is my code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eocCBMJeSotu9lRjHNxd?p=preview), I tried to import the component and call the function directly in my child component but I get this error: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined

How can I fix this?

Comment: what is the issue?? what you are trying to do

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I will try to give a complete answer to both cases that you may encounter:

**Case 1:** **Calling a child function from the parent component**

You can achieve this simply by using a template variable on your child selector to reference your child component in your parent component template and then you can call any public functions or property using that reference.

so in your child component, you got a function:

```
test(){
    console.log(`this is a test`);
}
```

and in your parent component you can call it in your parent component let's say after a button click just like this:

```
<child-component #childRef></child-component>
<button (click)="childRef.test()">
    Call the child test function
</button>
```

**Case 2: Calling a parent function from the child component**

This is a case it's up to your use case as you can inject the parent component in the child component and do the same as above but the relation is no longer be parent-child or child-parent but both components will be strongly linked together which is a rare use case. Alternatively, you can get the same result in a very simple way by using the `@Output` decorator to pass data and create your function in your child that will consume the data passed in.

so in your child component, you do the following:

```
@Output() childEvent = new EventEmitter();
test(){
    this.childEvent.emit('this is a test');
}
```

in your parent template

```
<child-component (childEvent)="test($event)"></child-component>
```

and then in your component

```
test(msg){
    console.log(msg);
}
```

Comment: If it wasn't accepted by the author, I would like to inform anyone who might encounter the same problem. Please change `message` in your parent template into `$event` for receiving any data from child component